# How to delete data from list with check condition

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

i have one list this list i have bind from webservices in webservice i have a one parameter in each list item the parameter is status . so i want  to check if status is 0 delete this particular item 
here my code

```
List<boko_data_json> thedata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<boko_data_json>>(json);
listname.ItemsSource = list.data;
foreach (var item in thedata)
{
   if(item.status == "0") {
       //How to DELETE THIS storage data from thedata List    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<boko_data_json> thedata = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<boko_data_json>>(json);
theData.RemoveAll(n => n.status == "0");
```

Comment: and i want also change a another parameter like in thedata have a one parameter book_purchasing it is also in class book_purchasing == yes how to change to particular list item

Comment: sorry my english is weak

Comment: you want to change `book_purchasing` value or remove item when `book_purchasing == yes`?

Comment: i want to change book_purchasing value when status ==1

Comment: Your question did not mention that you want to do something else with the item. You can do `foreach` loop after `RemoveAll` or do everything (remove/change) in `for (int i=0; i < thedata.Count; i++)` loop

Comment: this is another query . i dont want to change after removing i know this is not possible